# How do i resolve Call to a member function only() on array error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I want to use laravels FormRequest to validate before updating some fields. This works fine if i just use:

```
User::find($application->userid)->fill($request->only('first_name'...
```

but the request also contains sub array ($request->programmeData).

```
array:2 [▼
  "programme_id" => 5
  "programme_title" => "some programme title"
]
```

if i try access that the same way i get 'Call to a member function only() on array':

```
Course::find($application->userid)->fill($request->programmeData->only('programme_id...
```

I've tried a handful of things, but not sure best way to go with this?

**Update**
I'm now using a foreach loop to save two items in the array. the example below saves the second value for both user_ids. any reason this isn't saving the first value for the first user_id?

```
foreach ($request->programmeData['userProgrammes'] as $key=>$userProgrammes) {
   Course::where('application_id', $application->id)->get()[$key]->fill(Arr::only($request->programmeData['userProgrammes'][$key], ['programme_id']))->save();
}
```

but nothing updates. Any ideas on this one?

Comment: `$request`  is not an array but `$request->programmeData` is

Comment: As far as I know, `Model::fill()` needs key-value pairs instead of values only

Comment: `Arr::only($request->programmeData, ['programme_id'])` should be equivalent to `$request->programmeData['programme_id']`

Comment: @shaedrich thanks again, ive updated the question above - can you see why this would be updating both table rows with the second array value?

Comment: I updated my answer according to your update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array::only()` helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-array-only) for this:

```php
foreach ($request->programmeData['userProgrammes'] as $key=>$userProgrammes) {
   Course::where('application_id', $application->id)->first()->fill([
      $key => Arr::only($request->programmeData['userProgrammes'][$key], ['programme_id'])
   ])->save();
   // or
   $course = Course::where('application_id', $application->id)->first()
   $course->$key = Arr::only($request->programmeData['userProgrammes'][$key], ['programme_id']);
   $course->save();
}
//Arr::only($request->programmeData, ['programme_id', ...]);
```

Comment: im now using a foreach loop to save two items in the array: foreach ($request->programmeData['applicationProgrammes'] as $applicationProgramme) {
            Course::find($application->user_id)->fill(Arr::only($request->programmeData, ['programme_id']))->save();
        }. but nothing updates. any ideas on this one? thanks